# Maximize the quadratic form by choosing appropriate matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, optimization, terminology, quadratic-forms

What is the usual term/method for the functional optimization problem 
$$max_{Q\in\mathbb{S}_n}\quad x'Qx$$ with the constraint $x'x=1$ OR $x'1=$some constant? Notice that the maximizer should be a $n\times n$ matrix $Q\in\mathbb{S}_{n}$ whose entries are 0 or 1.

Comment: $x'Qx=\sum_{i,j=1}^n x_i Q_{ij} x_j$, so to my knowledge there would be no maximum available since the sum can get arbitrary large

Comment: @B.Swan Corrected.

Comment: You have to sort the values ($Q$ does that) in $(x_1, ..., x_n)=x$ by their value such that the $k$-th largest matchest the $k$-th largest on $x'$.

Comment: @B.Swan So there is no a specific term/method/theory for such a problem?

Comment: I do not know, but a permutation can swap the order of the values without changing their values. So to maximize the sum that I wrote in the first comment you would want the most of the biggest value (multiply the biggest value in $x$ by the biggest in $x'$, and the least of the least).

Comment: Is $\mathbb S_n$ the set of symmetric matrices? Is "$x'1=$some constant" supposed to be "$x'x$"? Are $x'$ and $x$ fixed or also varying as part of the optimization? If fixed, can't you just set $Q_{ij}=1$ if $x'_ix_j+x'_jx_i\geq0$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: @stewbasic $\mathbb{S}_n$ are binary matrices; $x$ are fixed; Yes, but for a smaller class of matrices like permutation matrices, how the result will change and mostly I want a name for such an optimization.